# REST Routing fails in ZF2 Rest Skeleton

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, restful-architecture

I configured the Resftul module (https://github.com/scaraveos/ZF2-Restful-Module-Skeleton) with the following module.config.php . But as I want to access "public/rest/article.json" the routing fails.

Does someone have a clue for me?
Controller is given.

```
return array(
    'errors' => array(
        'post_processor' => 'json-pp',
        'show_exceptions' => array(
            'message' => true,
            'trace'   => true
        )
    ),
    'di' => array(
        'instance' => array(
            'alias' => array(
                'json-pp'  => 'Rest\PostProcessor\Json',
                'image-pp' => 'Rest\PostProcessor\Image',
            )
        )
    ),
    'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'article' => 'Rest\Controller\ArticleController',
        )
    ),
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'restful' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'       => '/[:controller][.:formatter][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'formatter'  => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id'         => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

autoload_classmap is

```
'Rest\Controller\ArticleController' => __DIR__ . '/src/Rest/Controller/ArticleController.php',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want, but there's a better way to handle REST request, using the Content Type header to decide what format is to be shown.
ZF2 is good at doing this using View Strategies:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.quick-start.html#creating-and-registering-alternate-rendering-and-response-strategies

You can use a different strategy depending upon which content type is requested, which is what you should be doing with REST APIs.

You could rewrite your route to use something like this:

```
'route' => '/[:controller[.:format][/:id]]',
'constraints' => array(
    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
    'format' => '(xml|json|sphp)',
    'id' => '[1-9][0-9]*',
),
'defaults' => array(
    'controller' => 'Rest\Controller\ArticleController',
    'format' => 'xml',
),
```

You could then use routes such as '/articles.json/9' or /articles/xml

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what's you vhost configuration but if you are trying to access this url:

`http://somehost/public/rest/article.json`

Then you need to change this:

`'route'       => '/[:controller][.:formatter][/:id]',`

to this:

`'route'       => '/public/rest/[:controller][.:formatter][/:id]',`

Let me know if this works for you.